# How to teleport an entangled state via the two-qubit Heisenberg model?

Tags: entanglement, teleportation

I saw many articles that talk about entanglement teleportation via the two-qubit Heisenberg model as a quantum channel
for example look at this artiles
https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0808/0808.2406.pdf
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272621106_Quantum_teleportation_via_two-qubit_Heisenberg_XYZ_chain

but how to teleport an entanglement state via two-qubits?
state of **two** entanglement particles go in **a** qubit and exit from other one? how is it possible?

I know Bennett protocol to teleport a single unknown state. I just can't understand the teleportation of the state of two entanglement qubits via other two qubits.

If the inner state is a two-qubit state, where does it appear as output? it can't appear in a single qubit shared with Bob for sure.

Can somebody explain this to me by using a graph? or at least share a simple article or webpage that explains this?

Comment: please edit the post to add links to the sources you are referring to

Comment: Without further details it seems like a simple swap.